# Unable to install react-beautiful-dnd package

Tags: reactjs, npm

***Below is the full error stack message while installing the package**

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: freeboard@0.1.0
npm ERR! Found: react@17.0.1
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   react@"^17.0.1" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"^16.8.5" from react-beautiful-dnd@13.0.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react-beautiful-dnd
npm ERR!   react-beautiful-dnd@"^13.0.0" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
```

**Here is the complete code using the dragdropcontext and droppable from the package, the full component Main.
Here is the complete code using the dragdropcontext and droppable from the package, the full component Main.**

```
import { connect } from "react-redux"
import { DragDropContext, Droppable } from 'react-beautiful-dnd';


import SingleTask from "../SingleTask/SingleTask"

import "./Main.css"

const Main = (props) => {

    const [tasks, setTasks] = useState([])

    useEffect(() => {
        setTasks(...[props.tasks])
    },[props])


    return (
        <>
        <DragDropContext>
            <Droppable droppableId="Box1">
                {(provided) => (    
                    <div {...provided.droppableProps} ref={provided.innerRef}>
                        {provided.placeholder}
                        <div className="main-board">
                            <h2>FreeBoard</h2>

                            { tasks && tasks.map((task, index) => {
                                return (
                                    <div className="tasks-list" key={index}>
                                        <SingleTask taskName={task} indexCount={index}/>
                                    </div>
                                )
                            }) }
                        </div>
                    </div>
                )}
            </Droppable>
        </DragDropContext>
        </>
    )
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return state
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Main)
```

Comment: `npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps` Did you try these?

Comment: Tried that way, --legacy-peer-deps is not installing and --force is installing the package but unable to use the contents of that. eg. DragDropContext, etc are throwing errors like "Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you have a cache problem because it is working perfectly on my machine, with no errors. Remove node_modules , update npm `npm -g install npm`
and reinstall again everything.

Comment: I tried doing it forcefully. after installing if I use the DragDropContext I am getting the below error "Uncaught Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component."

Comment: You should not have two react versions in the same app. I do not remember what exactly forcing do, but I am pretty sure it is not a good idea. It can install two separate versions of react. You can check it by npm ls react. And can decrease your react version . But anyway react-beautiful-dnd is being installed perfectly on my app, which has react@17.0.1 installed.

Comment: Can you also show your code, where you are using `DragDropContext`? Maybe you are calling hook in a wrong way

Comment: Added the code above, I uninstalled and tried installing the package again without forcing it. Same error as above

Comment: Please provide all related code, with the whole component.

Comment: Or create some sandbox, with minimal reproduction

Comment: added the code. If it is'nt clear I will create a sandbox, please let me know

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224661/discussion-between-david-galoyan-and-harsha-ray).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.
Try to downgrate the react version. I changed from v18.1.0 to v17.0.2. It helps

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative drop-in replacement for react-beautiful-dnd try [hello pangea dnd](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@hello-pangea/dnd)

```
npm i @hello-pangea/dnd --save
```

Just replace the react-beautiful-dnd import line with:

```
import { DragDropContext } from '@hello-pangea/dnd';
```