# Dependency Issue, React DnD Beautiful

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

I'm trying to install the following package, which is well known.
However, I'm a little confused as to how to diagnose this issue. I'd like to use this package as it's a core concept of my site, drag and drop.

Is this saying I need react @16.14.0? How would I go about bumping the entire project up correctly? Will this cause issues with other packages?

I am quite new to React and specifically this concept of tree dependencies? I also know my packages may be messed up, and if I need to, I'm happy to try resolve with tips.

```
npm i react-beautiful-dnd
```

However I get these errors:

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: new@0.1.0
npm ERR! Found: react@16.8.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   peer react@">=16.8.0" from @emotion/react@11.7.0
npm ERR!   node_modules/@emotion/react
npm ERR!     peer @emotion/react@"^11.0.0-rc.0" from @emotion/styled@11.6.0   
npm ERR!     node_modules/@emotion/styled
npm ERR!       peerOptional @emotion/styled@"^11.3.0" from @mui/material@5.2.3
npm ERR!       node_modules/@mui/material
npm ERR!         peer @mui/material@"^5.0.0" from @mui/icons-material@5.2.4   
npm ERR!         node_modules/@mui/icons-material
npm ERR!         1 more (the root project)
npm ERR!       3 more (@mui/styled-engine, @mui/system, the root project)   
npm ERR!     peerOptional @emotion/react@"^11.5.0" from @mui/material@5.2.3 
npm ERR!     node_modules/@mui/material
npm ERR!       peer @mui/material@"^5.0.0" from @mui/icons-material@5.2.4   
npm ERR!       node_modules/@mui/icons-material
npm ERR!         @mui/icons-material@"^5.2.4" from the root project
npm ERR!       1 more (the root project)
npm ERR!     3 more (@mui/styled-engine, @mui/system, the root project)     
npm ERR!   peer react@">=16.8.0" from @emotion/styled@11.6.0
npm ERR!   node_modules/@emotion/styled
npm ERR!     peerOptional @emotion/styled@"^11.3.0" from @mui/material@5.2.3
npm ERR!     node_modules/@mui/material
npm ERR!       peer @mui/material@"^5.0.0" from @mui/icons-material@5.2.4   
npm ERR!       node_modules/@mui/icons-material
npm ERR!         @mui/icons-material@"^5.2.4" from the root project
npm ERR!       1 more (the root project)
npm ERR!     peerOptional @emotion/styled@"^11.3.0" from @mui/styled-engine@5.2.0
npm ERR!     node_modules/@mui/styled-engine
npm ERR!       @mui/styled-engine@"^5.2.0" from @mui/system@5.2.3
npm ERR!       node_modules/@mui/system
npm ERR!         @mui/system@"^5.2.3" from @mui/material@5.2.3
npm ERR!         node_modules/@mui/material
npm ERR!     2 more (@mui/system, the root project)
npm ERR!   22 more (@material-ui/core, @material-ui/icons, ...)
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! react-beautiful-dnd@"*" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: react@16.14.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   peer react@"^16.8.5 || ^17.0.0" from react-beautiful-dnd@13.1.0
npm ERR!   node_modules/react-beautiful-dnd
npm ERR!     react-beautiful-dnd@"*" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
```

It's worth noting my package.json looks:

```
{
  "name": "new",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@emotion/react": "^11.7.0",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.6.0",
    "@fontsource/roboto": "^4.5.1",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^4.11.2",
    "@mui/icons-material": "^5.2.4",
    "@mui/material": "^5.2.3",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.1.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.1.10",
    "framer-motion": "^4.1.17",
    "gsap": "^3.9.1",
    "material-ui-search-bar": "^1.0.0",
    "react": "^16.8.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.0",
    "react-draggable": "^4.4.4",
    "react-intersection-observer": "^8.33.1",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "react-typewriter-effect": "^1.1.0",
    "styled-components": "^5.3.3",
    "typewriter-effect": "^2.18.2",
    "web-vitals": "^1.0.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Is this saying I need react @16.14.0? How would I go about bumping the entire project up correctly? Will this cause issues with other packages?

Comment: You have multiple conflicts in the package.json, beside the new one: **typewriter-effect**, **@mui/material**, and **@mui/icons-material**. All of them seem to require React 17. Also having both **@material-ui/icons** and **@mui/icons-material**  seems redundant, as they  provide the same icon set.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your problem could be solved by removing the node_modules folder and running `npm -g install npm`, like this tutorial suggest: [Unable to install react-beautiful-dnd package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64873244/unable-to-install-react-beautiful-dnd-package)

Comment: Please don't answer obvious duplicates - just vtc as dupe once you have suffiecient rep or write a comment including the link..

Comment: I do not have a reputation to comment or vtc as a dupe.

Comment: Hence I wrote _"once you have suffiecient rep"_ -> If you don't - just move on to answering some other question..

Comment: `npm i react-beautiful-dnd --legacy-peer-deps` use this command